# Why is fairseq giving me "Operation not permitted" errors when I try to pip install it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I was trying to pip install fairseq but it gives me this error:

```
Collecting fairseq
  Using cached fairseq-0.10.2.tar.gz (938 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin/python /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/tmp53sqhb48
       cwd: /private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-install-9ezx6r70/fairseq_b257abb8318a4f5ba990ead01e05ee1d
  Complete output (31 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 214, in <module>
      do_setup(package_data)
    File "setup.py", line 136, in do_setup
      setup(
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 61, in fetch_build_eggs
      raise SetupRequirementsError(specifier_list)
  setuptools.build_meta.SetupRequirementsError: ['cython', 'numpy', 'setuptools>=18.0']

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 117, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jlth1u6g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 217, in <module>
      os.unlink(fairseq_examples)
  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'fairseq/examples'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/59/1f466d82d64482e2809a167e0067979c23057b3752e668537d5ff24453c9/fairseq-0.10.2.tar.gz#sha256=45b90d8ccc3f5a4623a523fe2d0465f54413d03fd1ec9a9d7af0461148ca1a68 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fairseq/). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin/python /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/tmp53sqhb48 Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached fairseq-0.10.1.tar.gz (924 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin/python /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/tmpy7vu5hbe
       cwd: /private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-install-9ezx6r70/fairseq_e62eaebbbe434dba97d009e1990626c7
  Complete output (31 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 214, in <module>
      do_setup(package_data)
    File "setup.py", line 136, in do_setup
      setup(
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 61, in fetch_build_eggs
      raise SetupRequirementsError(specifier_list)
  setuptools.build_meta.SetupRequirementsError: ['cython', 'numpy', 'setuptools>=18.0']

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 117, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-078mczov/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 217, in <module>
      os.unlink(fairseq_examples)
  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'fairseq/examples'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/00/8668312a50a607d1ceb4a6f0804662a04f7b029857679f518a2ec4777d75/fairseq-0.10.1.tar.gz#sha256=05b9e6bea4fc974b33e0ee5c154ec4069c6996be30c53d3ea8dd6d13113170f2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fairseq/). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/bin/python /Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vz/9vkmdqbn3ml_12rcbh66rn4c0000gn/T/tmpy7vu5hbe Check the logs for full command output.
```

which seems very puzzling because it seems it goes on to import things just fine:

```
❯ python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fairseq
>>>
```

should I be worried about this?

Also, it doesn't feel right to have to sudo install things with pip...

---

related:

- https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/issues/3535